# Find document by search of a value in different fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, kibana

I am new to Elastic and Kibana and I would like to find a solution to the problem of fetching objects from Elastic that contains a value in different fields.

For example if documents are mapped as:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "XXXX",
    "_score" : 12,
    "_source" : {
      "id1" : "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "id2" : "YYYYYYYYYY",
      "id3" : "ZZZZZZZZZZ"
```

I want to be able to make a query on all 3 ID blindly to find the document corresponding, and if there are no IDs that corresponds to my value, then the query sends no results instead of another result with a lesser score.

I tried with a combination of bool: must and should. Must on fields such as lastname and firstname, and Should on the IDs but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You tried with [Multi-Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)?

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "Will Smith",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "first_name", "last_name" ],
      "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```